# macOS Terminal not using correct manpath

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path, command-line

How to set `$MANPATH` or `manpath` for the macOS Terminal **Help** menu command: **Open man Page for Selection**?

Having recently done a clean install of macOS Mojave (10.14.6), I am trying to get my macOS Terminal.app configured.  The trouble is with the Terminal menu command **Open man Page** or **Open man Page for Selection** and its associated service available system wide in the **Services** menu.  I would like to configure the `manpath` that the menu command is using to be the same as my bash shell.

The standard `/usr/bin/man` command works great from my shell.  But I like to be able to select a word or topic or command in the Terminal and right click.  The context menu has **Open man Page** and **Services ► Open man Page in Terminal**.  I use the last one a lot becase it works anywhere.  The menu command opens a new window in Terminal containing the complete formatted man page text, with a special window profile / color scheme, without disturbing my current shell session.

My specific problem is illustrated as follows.  If I select "bash", right click, and **Open man Page**, then the man page I get is for bash 3.2.  It is almost certainly the from `/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1`.
If I type `man bash` in the Terminal shell, I get the man page for bash 5.0: `/usr/local/share/man/man1/bash.1`.  Typing man -aw bash, I get

```bsh
$ man -aw bash
/usr/local/share/man/man1/bash.1
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1
```

If I type manpath, replacing colons with newlines, I get

```bsh
$ manpath | perl -nE 's/:/\n/g; print'
/opt/local/share/man
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/share/man
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
/usr/local/opt/ack/share/man
```

I don’t know how to query the Terminal for manpath it is using, or configure it.  Please help with any advice on how to configure the Terminal menu command **Open man Page for Selection**.

---

More information:

```
cbedgar@CBmac: ~  | 14:22:38 | -bash5.0.11
293$ man -d
Reading config file /private/etc/man.conf
Looked whether there exists a message catalog man, but there is none
(and for English messages none is needed)

found man directory /usr/local/share/man
found man directory /opt/local/share/man
found man directory /usr/share/man
found man directory /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man
found man directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man
found man directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/ack/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/bash/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gdbm/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gettext/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gnupg/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gnupg2/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gnupg@2.2/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gnutls/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gpg/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/gpg2/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/grep/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/jq/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libevent/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libffi/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libgcrypt/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libgpg-error/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libidn2/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libtasn/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libtasn1/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/libxml2/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/openssl/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/pandoc/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/pcre/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/pcre1/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/perl/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/perl@5.30/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/pure-ftpd/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/python/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/python2/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/python3/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/python@2/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/python@3/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/readline/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/sqlite/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/sqlite3/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/unbound/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/opt/xz/share/man
found manpath map /bin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /sbin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /usr/bin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /usr/sbin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /usr/local/bin --> /usr/local/share/man
found manpath map /usr/local/sbin --> /usr/local/share/man
found manpath map /usr/X11/bin --> /usr/X11/man
found manpath map /usr/bin/X11 --> /usr/X11/man
found manpath map /usr/bin/mh --> /usr/share/man

using /usr/bin/less -is as pager

using /usr/bin/less -is as browser

using /bin/cat to dump HTML pages as textWhat manual page do you want?
```

Comment: run `man manpath` or `man man` to see details. `/private/etc/man.conf` is where the configuration file sits. I just saw this thing for the first time, so cannot add more.

Comment: Can your post the command  and results of `man -d` ?

Comment: The man pages for manpath and man have been open all morning, but good suggestion anyway.  The [user guide for Terminal](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/welcome/mac) wasn't much help either.  I had tried editing ``/etc/manpaths`` or adding a file to ``/etc/manpaths.d/`` and rebooting to no avail.  Editing ``/etc/man.conf`` was a great thought, so I just tried adding my changes and rebooting.  No difference.  I still get the wrong bash manual.  THANK YOU for the suggestions however.

Comment: I suspect this is the uual issue of running from Finder as Terminal does - then your ~/.bash_profile etc are not loaded.

Comment: For bash, I would put the MANPATH definition into your .bashrc ; but test it first inside your bash shell, whether it works, before editing your startup file.

Answer (score 1):

In my use case, Terminal `Open man Page` was not working for 3rd-party software on Apple ARM-based macOS Ventura. e.g., Homebrew, MacTeX.

Also, the `x-man-page://` URI Scheme for Terminal.app was not working in the same scenario. Example use of `x-man-page` in markdown:

*FFmpegQuickReference.md*

```markdown
# [FFmpeg][t] Quick Reference
[t]:x-man-page://1/ffmpeg

man pages: [ffmpeg](x-man-page://1/ffmpeg), [ffprobe](x-man-page://1/ffprobe)

… snip …
```

The Ventura `man` page shows `/usr/local/etc/man.d` in the FILES section:

```
FILES
     /etc/man.conf
             System configuration file.
     /usr/local/etc/man.d/*.conf
             Local configuration files.
```

Here's a solution for macOS Ventura (Apple ARM) which worked for both `Open man Page` menu item and `x-man-page` URI:

```sh
### check for presence of man.d directory
ls -l /usr/local/etc
### add these directories if not already present
sudo mkdir /usr/local/etc
sudo mkdir /usr/local/etc/man.d

cd /usr/local/etc/man.d
sudo touch man.conf
sudo nano man.conf

### View in Finder:
open /usr/local/etc
```

Contents of `/usr/local/etc/man.d/man.conf`:

```sh
### :EDIT:2023.10.01: Created /usr/local/etc/man.d/man.conf

### Homebrew
MANPATH /opt/homebrew/share/man
MANPATH /opt/homebrew/Cellar/*/*/share/man

### MacTeX 2023
MANPATH /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/man

### XQuartz X11
MANPATH /opt/X11/share/man
```

Alternately, a `*.man.conf` file can be created for each 3rd-party distribution.

```
usr
└── local
    └── etc
        └── man.d
            ├── homebrew.man.conf
            ├── mactex.man.conf
            └── xquartz.man.conf
```

---

**Addendum**

See Homebrew issue ["Terminal.app 'Open man Page' context menu and 'x-man-page' URI scheme not working in Apple Silicon for brew formulae"](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/16074) for additional discussion on this topic.

Comment: One caveat is that `/etc/man.conf` has precedence over `/usr/local/etc/man.d/*.conf `. If you install a newer version of a system package via Homebrew (e.g. rsync), the Terminal.app will continue using the old man.